# update from python 3.5 to 3.6: unable to install any packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, installation, python-3.6

I had the bad idea of upgrading python from 3.5 to 3.6. Now I cannot reinstall any packages I use (scipy, numpy,..).

The command I use `pip3 install -U numpy`

`pip3 --version` returns

```
pip 9.0.1
```

I have a licensed installation of Visual Studio 2015 community.

I'm on Win7 x64, I set as env var `VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%`

The last 5 rows of the huge error I get are:

```
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-65uc3b3g\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(c
ode, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-huz2nklc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-65uc3b3g\numpy\
```

Comment: Rather than compiling from source, you can get an already compiled version from Christoph Gohlke: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy That will avoid this problem

Comment: Do you have "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0"? Find it at http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools as stated by the error message...

Comment: @Bakuriu as I said I have a licensed Visual Studio 2015 so I do have the Visual C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

Next, create a Python 3.6 environment:

```
conda create -n py36 Python=3.6
```

activate it:

```
activate py36
```

The prompt should change to:

```
(py36)
```

and start installing your packages:

```
conda install numpy
```

You might want add the channel `conda-forge` to increase the number of available packages:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```